# make terminal real transparent

Tags: x11, terminal-emulator

I want to make terminal transparent.To do this I have to select option Transparent background and move the slider under Background tab from the menu - Edit -> Profile Preferences. It becomes transparent but only the desktop wallpaper is shown in the background.

But I want to see actual open applications or windows on the background. How do I do this?

I'm using Linux `[CentOS]` machine 
![My Desktop][1]
![after making changes in  terminal ][2]

Comment: fyi works out of the box on Ubuntu/  CentOS must be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to install **Compiz** from the [EPEL repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Comment: or a window manager that can handle compositing without compiz...

Comment: Yeah, but in this case, Compiz would likely be the best/easiest solution.